# React + React Router + Laravel => erro ao realizar refresh ou inserir url manualmente no navegador

Tags: laravel, react, route, react-router

Estou utilizando o React para o front de uma aplicação em laravel. No React, através do react-router estou acessando componentes dinamicamente através dos parâmetros passados via url pelo link do router. Se deixar as configurações default do laravel,

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('main');
 });
```

se atualizar a página ou inserir manualmente a url no navegador cai na página 404. Achei essa maneira de evitar isso:

```
Route::any('{all}', function () {
return view('main');
})
->where(['all' => '.*']);
```

No entanto isso só funciona para a primeira barra após o endereço do servidor. ex:

funciona:

```
http:127.0.0.1:8000/rota1
```

mas não funciona:

```
http:127.0.0.1:8000/rota1/subrota
```

Nesse caso, ao atualizar a página ou inserir url manualmente,  ao invés de cair no 404 a página fica em branco.

Como estou usando as rotas dinâmicas:

```
<Route exact path="/party/:action" component={OperationParty}/>          
<Route exact path="/party/:action/:id" render={(props) => 
       <OperationParty {...props} toogleLoading={this.setLoading} />}/>
```